# Responsive Image Masking compatible with IE

Tags: css, svg, clip

[image]

I would like to achieve the above.  The image is clipped, then there is a surrounding border around the image, which is clipped as well.  I have actually done it for Chrome and Firefox using CSS clip path - http://staging.web2-hk.redantdev.com/plukka-html/about.html

The clip path property for complex shape isn't supported in any IE - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path.

I would like to know another technique to make this work in IE Edge at the least.

Comment: You'd need to use an SVG `<image>` element and an SVG `<clipPath>` via the clip-path property.

Comment: @RobertLongson that works but I don't know how to make the image fluid to its container

Comment: use objectBoundingBoxUnits

Comment: @eirikrl did you manage to sort this out? I am in the same position with clippath working on the svg image but I can't get the image to be fluid width?